# Are these electronics-related questions on topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

There have been some arguments that the following two questions (and perhaps others like them) are off topic at this site, and perhaps should be migrated to electronics.SE. What does the community think?

- https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/11326/what-causes-hard-working-growling-sound-in-a-heavily-loaded-electric-motor
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/11335/why-do-we-need-brushed-motors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the migration of [Why do we need brushed motors?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11335/520) from an electronics.SE moderator:

> This question did alright, but Electronics.SE is about designing electronics and actually does not include mechanical issues such as motors except at a superficial level. We will see if that changes, but unless it is a good motor question, please do not migrate. – Kortuk

Now we have at least one rule about things to *not* migrate.

Comment: I guess we should have asked on Electronics' meta.

Answer (score 3):

It might be worth getting some feedback from Electronics.SE. They certainly have more of an engineering/design feel to them, but both of these particular questions could have been asked before the discovery of the electron, and thus predate "electronics" as such.

I'll pop over to their chat and ask people to have a look.

Comment: Did you ever get a response on this?

Comment: Not on the Chat. I think Matt might have come by in response to it.

Comment: OK, I guess I will try migrating them then.

Answer (score 1):

I for one wouldn't think of this kind of question as out of place on Electronics.SE.  I would see physics as more theoretical, and E.SE as more practical.